# Nested list no longer nested

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

im trying to code this simple currency converter, its pretty much a function  that takes a nested list of foreign currencies and their conversion rate as a parameter.
it seems to work ok and and gives the correct results but its not longer in the same format (?)

```py
for factor in [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ,90,100]:
     for num in [['AUD', 0.96],['USD', 0.75],['Euro', 0.67],['GBP', 0.496]]:
          product = num[1] * factor
          print(product)
```

this is what the result is suppose to look like:

```
[[10, 9.6, 7.5, 6.7, 4.96],
[20, 19.2, 15.0, 13.4, 9.92],
[30, 28.799999999999997, 22.5, 20.1, 14.879999999999999],
[40, 38.4, 30.0, 26.8, 19.84],
[50, 48.0, 37.5, 33.5, 24.8], [60, 57.599999999999994, 45.0, 40.2, 29.759999999999998],
[70, 67.2, 52.5, 46.900000000000006, 34.72], [80, 76.8, 60.0, 53.6, 39.68],
[90, 86.39999999999999, 67.5, 60.300000000000004, 44.64],
[100, 96.0, 75.0, 67.0, 49.6]]
```

instead mine is just a long list:
9.6
7.5
6.7
4.96
19.2
15.0
13.4
9.92.....

how do i implement this so that it stays within their lists?

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for factor in [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ,90,100]:
  temp = [factor]
  for num in [['AUD', 0.96],['USD', 0.75],['Euro', 0.67],['GBP', 0.496]]:
      product = num[1] * factor
      print(product)
      temp.append(product)
  result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

your code should something like this to get expected results

Answer (score 0):

```
final_list = []
for factor in [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]:
    temp_list = [factor]
    for num in [['AUD', 0.96], ['USD', 0.75], ['Euro', 0.67], ['GBP', 0.496]]:
       temp_list.append(num[1] * factor)
    final_list.append(temp_list)
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should fix your indentation error. I don't think you will be getting the output which you mentioned you are getting with this code. And you can try this to get the desired output:

```
res = []
for factor in [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ,90,100]:
    c = [factor]
    for num in [['AUD', 0.96],['USD', 0.75],['Euro', 0.67],['GBP', 0.496]]:
            c.append(num[1]*factor)
    res.append(c)

print(res)
```

Output:-

```
[[10, 9.6, 7.5, 6.7, 4.96],
[20, 19.2, 15.0, 13.4, 9.92],
[30, 28.799999999999997, 22.5, 20.1, 14.879999999999999],
[40, 38.4, 30.0, 26.8, 19.84],
[50, 48.0, 37.5, 33.5, 24.8], [60, 57.599999999999994, 45.0, 40.2, 29.759999999999998],
[70, 67.2, 52.5, 46.900000000000006, 34.72], [80, 76.8, 60.0, 53.6, 39.68],
[90, 86.39999999999999, 67.5, 60.300000000000004, 44.64],
[100, 96.0, 75.0, 67.0, 49.6]]
```

Comment: You can put the above code inside the function and return `res` through the function. Also, you can take the lists `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ,90,100]`, `[['AUD', 0.96],['USD', 0.75],['Euro', 0.67],['GBP', 0.496]]` as parameters to the function. If this solves your problem, do accept it.